# Slide animation between UIButtons

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ios-animations

I have been trying to set slide left & right animation between **UIButton**s which is located on the image below, a user can drags the right button to center button(right to left) and similarly drags the left button to center button(left to right). Also, after dragging process finished, if the user dragged left button to the center, left button will be the current button and current button will be the previous button. After this operation, the new view will be as 2nd week(previous), 3rd Week(current), 4th Week(next). Is there any possible way to make this animation between these **UIButton**s?
[image: visualization]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [slick carousel's Center Mode](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/). It does exactly what you're looking for! It looks great and is easy to use.

Comment: Actually, I completely want to slide between UIButtons like "Center Mode" on the link that you recommended. However, Is it possible to implement it on Swift ? @vveleva